# contiguous sublists from an ascending sequence

Tags: list, haskell, sequence

given

`xs = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11]`

I am aiming to return

`[[1,2,3,4],[6,7],[9,10,11]]`

I thought I could do:

`groupBy (\x y -> succ x == y) xs`

but this returns:

`[[1,2],[3,4],[6,7],[9,10],[11]]`

a little bit of searching returned the following from the Haskell Data.List suggestion [page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_function_suggestions#Generalize_groupBy_and_friends).

```
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
 groupBy rel []          =  []
 groupBy rel (x:xs)      =  (x:ys) : groupBy rel zs
   where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
         groupByAux x0 (x:xs) | rel x0 x = (x:ys, zs)
           where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
         groupByAux y xs = ([], xs)
```

One of the examples they give is exacly what I am looking for:

```
groupBy (\a b -> a+1 == b) [1,2,3,4,6]
[[1,2,3,4],[6]]
```

So My question... Is there another approach to this, as opposed to re-defining `groupBy` as it seems a little dramatic?

EDIT...

I have decided to implement it as follows:

```
pattern :: (Enum a, Eq a) => (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
pattern f = foldr g []
  where g a [] = [[a]]
        g a xs | f a == head (head xs) = (a : head xs): tail xs
               | otherwise = [a]:xs
```

which allows for such things:

```
*Main Map> pattern succ "thisabcdeisxyz"
["t","hi","s","abcde","i","s","xyz"]
*Main Map> pattern (+ 3) [3,6,9,12,1,2,3,2,5,8,23,24,25]
[[3,6,9,12],[1],[2],[3],[2,5,8],[23],[24],[25]]
```

or to function exactly like `group` -- not that there is any reason:

```
*Main Map> let xs = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,5]
*Main Map> group xs == pattern id xs
True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. One way can be using foldr

```
f = foldr g []
  where g a [] = [[a]]
        g a xs@(x:xs') | a+1 == head x = (a : x): xs'
                       | otherwise = [a]:xs
```

Now trying this in action

```
*Main> f [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11]
[[1,2,3,4],[6,7],[9,10,11]]
```

Comment: You could/should pattern match on `xs` in `g`, I.e. `g a xs@(x:xs')` and use `x` and `xs'` in place of the head and tail calls.

Comment: @dbaupp I did that before but all the way to second level and that made code very unreadable. It is better to use it for just one level.

Answer (score 3):

If `xs` is strictly increasing then

```
 myGrouping = map (map snd) . groupBy (\(u, v) (x, y) -> u - v == x - y) . zip [0..]
```

solve your problem.

```
Prelude> myGrouping [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11]
[[1,2,3,4],[6,7],[9,10,11]]
```