# Implement insert in haskell with foldr

Tags: list, haskell, insert, lambda, fold

How to implement insert using foldr in haskell.
I tried:

```
insert'' :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert'' e xs = foldr (\x -> \y -> if x<y then x:y else y:x) [e] xs
```

No dice.
I have to insert element e in list so that it goes before first element that is larger or equal to it.

Example:

```
insert'' 2.5 [1,2,3] => [1.0,2.0,2.5,3.0]
insert'' 2.5 [3,2,1] => [2.5,3.0,2.0,1.0]
insert'' 2 [1,2,1]   => [1,2,2,1]
```

In last example first 2 is inserted one.

EDIT:
Thanks @Lee.

I have this now:

```
insert'' :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert'' e xs = insert2 e (reverse xs)
insert2 e = reverse .  snd . foldr (\i (done, l) -> if (done == False) && (vj e i) then (True, e:i:l) else (done, i:l)) (False, [])
    where vj e i = e<=i
```

But for this is not working:

```
insert'' 2 [1,3,2,3,3] => [1,3,2,2,3,3]
insert'' 2 [1,3,3,4]   => [1,3,2,3,4]
insert'' 2 [4,3,2,1]   => [4,2,3,2,1]
```

SOLUTION:

```
insert'' :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert'' x xs = foldr pom poc xs False
  where
    pom y f je
      | je || x > y = y : f je
      | otherwise   = x : y : f True
    poc True = []
    poc _    = [x]
```

Thanks @Pedro Rodrigues (It just nedded to change x>=y to x>y.)

(How to mark this as answered?)

Comment: folds are normally used for reducing lists, not expanding them.  Also, your description and your third example are conflicting.  By your description it should be inserted before the 3, like in your first example.

Comment: @bheklilr: What is the best way of solving this ? Is it explicit recursion or any higher order function exists for solving this ?

Comment: Quite an important note: `if x<y then x:y else y:x` will never work. `(:)` is a constructor that takes an element (type `a`) on the left hand side, and a list (type `[a]`) on the right hand side. However, `(<)` takes two arguments of the same type. Since Haskell doesn't allow infinite types, `a` and `[a]` can never be of the same type. I understand your confusion, but please understand that `x:y:z:w` means `x:(y:(z:w))`, so `x, y, z :: a` and `w :: [a]`.

Comment: @excrucio To mark as answered, you have to click on the check of your preferred answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take at it:

```haskell
insert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert x xs = foldr aux initial xs False
  where
    aux y f done
      | done || x > y = y : f done
      | otherwise = x : y : f True
    initial True = []
    initial _ = [x]
```

However IMHO using `foldr` is not the best fit for this problem, and for me the following solution is easier to understand:

```haskell
insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert x [] = [x]
insert x z@(y : ys)
  | x <= y = x : z
  | otherwise = y : insert x ys
```

Comment: your last solution is explicitly recursive. The point of using `fodlr` is to be *implicitly* recursive, to let the `foldr` to encapsulate the recursion. The very use of `foldr` indicates recursion; the explicitly recursive code needs to be interpreted by a (human) mind, so "more clean" is in the eyes of the beholder. :)

Comment: @WillNess Granted a "cleaner" solution is very subjective, so I've changed the wording to state that it's just my opinion. The problem could also be solved with using implicit recursion using `unfoldr`, but so what? I still find the explicitly recursive solution easier to understand that any of the `foldr` solutions.

Comment: of course, I never claimed you *should* be doing this or that. :) -- BTW `unfoldr` encapsulates *corecursion*. Just nitpicking. :)

Comment: @WillNess Hmm nitpicking... are you acquainted with [exercism](http://exercism.io/)?

Comment: (you didn't use it, so I went ahead and edited it into my answer). :)

Answer (score 3):

You need [*paramorphism*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317563/849891) for that:

```
para  :: (a -> [a] -> r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r
foldr :: (a ->        r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r

para  c n (x : xs) = c x xs (para c n xs)
foldr c n (x : xs) = c x    (foldr c n xs)
para  _ n []       = n
foldr _ n []       = n
```

with it,

```
insert v xs = para (\x xs r -> if v <= x then (v:x:xs) else (x:r)) [v] xs
```

---

We can imitate paramorphisms with `foldr` over `init . tails`, as can be seen here: [Need to partition a list into lists based on breaks in ascending order of elements (Haskell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403293/need-to-partition-a-list-into-lists-based-on-breaks-in-ascending-order-of-elemen/14451312#14451312).

Thus the solution is

```
import Data.List (tails)

insert v xs = foldr g [v] (init $ tails xs)
  where
    g xs@(x:_) r | v <= x    = v : xs
                 | otherwise = x : r
```

---

Another way to encode paramorphisms is by a chain of functions, as seen in the [answer by Pedro Rodrigues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20569505/849891), to arrange for the *left-to-right* information flow while passing a second copy of the input list *itself* as an argument (replicating the effect of `tails`):

```
insert v xs = foldr g (\ _ -> [v]) xs xs
  where
    g x r xs | v > x     = x : r (tail xs)   -- xs =@= (x:_)
             | otherwise = v : xs

-- visual aid to how this works, for a list [a,b,c,d]:
-- g a (g b (g c (g d (\ _ -> [v])))) [a,b,c,d]
```

Unlike the version in his answer, this does not copy the rest of the list structure after the insertion point (which is possible because of paramorphism's  "eating the cake and having it too").

Answer (score 1):

I suppose fold isn't handy here. It always processes *all* elements of list, but you need to stop then first occurence was found.
Of course it is possible, but you probable don't want to use this:

```
insert' l a = snd $ foldl (\(done, l') b -> if done then (True, l'++[b]) else if a<b then (False, l'++[b]) else (True, l'++[a,b])) (False, []) l
```

Comment: This is with foldl and I do not get it.
And why my if is not working?

Comment: @excrucio Your program doesn't even type check so it is too soon to debug it.

Comment: Ok, I know, but what I am doing wrong. My "if" seems to me ok, but when I look at your, you use "\\(done, l') b" and I do not get why is that.
Maybe a stupid question, but I am new to Haskell.

Comment: @excrucio For example in your code there are `x:y` and `y:x`. Thus if x has type a then y must to have type [a]. But second bit of code requires vice versa types. Try to read compiler errors carefully.

Comment: @excrucio `done` is used to track whether the element was already inserted, so it's not inserted multiple times.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. Example: `insert' [1,2] 6 == [6,1,2]`