# How to access the next element when using the map function?

Tags: list, haskell, map-function

I am trying to apply a function on each element of a list in haskell. Therefore I am using the `map` function.
My code should add the value of the next element to the current element.

So I think my code should look somehow like this:

```
test :: [Rational]
test = map (\x -> x % {-somehow get next element -}) listT
```

`listT` is an infinite list of type Int.

But how do I "access" the next value?
Thx for your help

Comment: use `zipWith` with the list and its tail.

Comment: What should the result of `test [1,2..]` be? `[3,5,7,9,...]`, or `[3,6,10,...]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you. The `zipWith` Function was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

To access the next element, map on [`tails`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=tails) instead:

```
mapWithNext op xs = map g (tails xs)
  where
  g (x:y:_) = Just (op x y)
  g _       = Nothing
```

since when there's no next element, your `op` can't be applied, though it will only happen with the finite lists. You might *know* that the input lists will be infinite, but your type doesn't, so it's better to be on the safe side.

You might want to add a post-processing step to get rid of the final `Nothing`(s) and extract the `Just` values. [`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=catMaybes) seems applicable.

Of course using `zipWith`(*) mentioned in the comments is cleaner and more to the point, here; but this way with `tails` is more versatile in general, i.e. it is easier to amend to be used with e.g. *ternary* `op`, etc.. With `zipWith` we'd have to use a chain of nested `zipWith` applications and build artificial tuples just to have access to the elements; with `tails` we don't need to do anything like that at all.

A combination of `map` (generally, `foldr`) with `tails` is actually [emulating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22051606/849891) *paramorphism*. [It has its merits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14451312/849891) so as e.g. in Common Lisp it is actually present as a library function [`maplist`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm).

(*) you could say, `zipWith` is *not* map, but   e.g. in Scheme it is so. There, `map` accepts an arbitrary number of argument lists, and a combining operation of the corresponding arity. But of course Haskell is not Scheme.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `zipWith` and zip the list with its tail:

```
mapWithNext :: [Rational]
mapWithNext = zipWith (\x1 x2 -> …) listT (tail listT)
```