# How do I combine consectuive numbers in a list into a range in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to grapple my head around Haskell and I'm having a hard time pinning down the general procedure/algorithm for this specific task. What I want to do is basically give Haskell a list [1,2,3,5,6,9,16,17,18,19] and have it give me back [1-3, 5, 6, 9, 16-19] so essentially turning three or more consecutive numbers into a range in the style of lowestnumber - highestnumber. What I have issue with it I suppose is the all too common difficulty grappling with with the functional paradigm of Haskell. So I would really appreciate a general algorithm or an insight into how to view this from an "Haskellian" point of view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a dupe but [a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14403293/4543207). It may help you to construct the result that you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the idea is to break up the input lists in chunks, where a chunk is either a single input element or a range of at least three consecutive elements.

So, let's start by defining a datatype for representing such chunks:

```
data Chunk a = Single a | Range a a
```

As you can see, the type is parametric in the type of input elements.

Next, we define a function `chunks` to actually construct a list of chunks from a list of input elements. For this, we require the ability to compare input elements and to obtain the immediate consecutive for a given input element (that is, its successor). Hence, the type of the function reads

```
chunks :: (Eq a, Enum a) => [a] -> [Chunk a]
```

Implementation is relatively straightforward:

```
chunks = foldr go []
 where
  go x (Single y : Single z : cs) | y == succ x && z == succ y = Range x z : cs
  go x (Range y z : cs) | y == succ x = Range x z : cs
  go x cs                             = Single x : cs
```

We traverse the list from right to left, generating chunks as we go. We generate a range if an input element precedes its two immediate consecutive elements (the first case of the helper function `go`) or if it precedes a range that starts with its immediate consecutive (the second case). Otherwise, we generate a single element (the final case).

To arrange for pretty output, we declare applications of the type constructor `Chunk` to be instances of the class `Show` (given that the type of input elements is in `Show`):

```
instance Show a => Show (Chunk a) where
  show (Single x ) = show x
  show (Range x y) = show x ++ "-" ++ show y
```

Returning to the example from the question, we then have:

```
> chunks [1,2,3,5,6,9,16,17,18,19]
[1-3,5,6,9,16-19]
```

---

Unfortunately, things are slightly more complicated if we need to account for bounded element types; such types have a largest element for which `succ` is undefined:

```
> chunks [maxBound, 1, 2, 3] :: [Chunk Int]
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.succ{Int}: tried to take `succ' of maxBound
```

This suggests that we should abstract from the specific approach for determining whether one elements succeeds another:

```
chunksBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Chunk a]
chunksBy succeeds = foldr go []
 where
  go x (Single y : Single z : cs) | y `succeeds` x && z `succeeds` y =
    Range x z : cs
  go x (Range y z : cs) | y `succeeds` x = Range x z : cs
  go x cs = Single x : cs
```

Now, the version of `chunks` that was given above, can be expressed in terms of `chunksBy` simply by writing

```
chunks :: (Eq a, Enum a) => [a] -> [Chunk a]
chunks = chunksBy (\y x -> y == succ x)
```

Moreover, we can now also implement a version for bounded input types as well:

```
chunks' :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => [a] -> [Chunk a]
chunks' = chunksBy (\y x -> x /= maxBound && y == succ x)
```

That merrily gives us:

```
> chunks' [maxBound, 1, 2, 3] :: [Chunk Int]
[9223372036854775807,1-3]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the very elaborate explanation!

Comment: This is wrong for bounded types. `chunks ([127, 1, 2, 3] :: [Int8])` should be `[127, 1-3]`, but it actually errors with ``*** Exception: Enum.succ{Int8}: tried to take `succ' of maxBound``.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes, that's a good catch. So, depending on the actual use case, I'd argue to either use a monomorphic implementation of `chunks` (if needed adapted to protect against overflows) or otherwise implement a version that accounts for bounded types as well. I'll update the answer. Thanks a lot for pointing this out!

Comment: Definitely better now. Suggestion: since most `Enum`s also have a reasonable `Ord` instance, you could do `chunksBy (\y x -> y > x && y == succ x)` to have just one function that works on almost any type you'd want to use it with, whether bounded or not.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's a nice one as well. `Ord` seems like a reasonable constraint for most occurrences of this problem in the wild.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans After asking [my own question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61688753/7509065), it turns out there's an even better approach: `chunksBy (\y x -> case [x..y] of [_,_] -> True; _ -> False)` And it doesn't even need an `Eq` constraint!

Answer (score 1):

First, all elements of a list must be of the same type. Your resulting list has two different types. `Range`s (for what ever that means) and `Int`s. We should convert one single digit into a range with lowest and highest been the same.

Been said so, You should define the `Range` data type and fold your list of `Int` into a list of `Range`

```
data Range = Range {from :: Int , to :: Int}

intsToRange :: [Int] -> [Range]
intsToRange [] = []
intsToRange [x] = [Range x x]
intsToRange (x:y:xs) = ...  -- hint: you can use and auxiliar acc which holds the lowest value and keep recursion till find a y - x differece greater than 1.
```

You can also use `fold`, etc... to get a very haskelly point of view

Answer (score 1):

Use *recursion*. Recursion is a leap of faith. It is imagining you've already written your definition and so can (*"recursively"*) call *it* on a sub-problem of your full problem, and combine the (recursively calculated) sub-result with the left-over part to get the full solution -- *easy*:

```
ranges xs  =  let  (leftovers, subproblem) = split xs
                   subresult = ranges subproblem
                   result = combine leftovers subresult
              in
                   result
   where
   split xs  =  ....
   combine as rs  =  ....
```

Now, we know the type of `rs` in `combine` (i.e. `subresult` in `ranges`) -- it is what `ranges` returns:

```
ranges :: [a] -> rngs
```

So, how do we `split` our input list `xs`? The *type-oriented design* philosophy says, *follow the type*.

`xs` is a list `[a]` of `a`s. This type has two cases: `[]` or `x:ys` with `x :: a` and `ys :: [a]`. So the easiest way to split a list into a smaller list and some leftover part is

```
    split (x:xs)  =  (x, ys)
    split []      =  *error* "no way to do this"   -- intentionally invalid code
```

Taking note of the last case, we'll have to tweak the overall design to take that into account. But first things first, what's the *`rngs`* type could be? Going by your example data, it's a list of `rng`s, naturally, `rngs ~ [rng]`.

A `rng` type though, we have a considerable degree of freedom to make it to be whatever we want. The cases we have to account for are pairs and singletons:

```
data Rng a  =  Single a 
            |  Pair a a
```

.... and now we need to fit the jagged pieces together into one picture.

Combining a number with a range which starts from consecutive number is obvious.

Combining a number with a single number will have two obvious cases, for whether those numbers are consecutive or not.

I think / hope you can proceed from here.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the very elaborate explanation!

I think I'm starting to understand it a bit better