# How can I determine if one Enum value is the successor of another?

Tags: haskell, enums, bounded-types

I'm trying to write a function that tells me whether one `Enum` is the successor of another. Here was my first attempt:

```
isSuccessorOf x y = x == succ y
```

Looks reasonable. Let's try it:

```
λ> isSuccessorOf 3 2
True
λ> isSuccessorOf 1 5
False
λ> isSuccessorOf 3 (maxBound :: Int)
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.succ{Int}: tried to take `succ' of maxBound
```

Whoops. That should have been `False`. Let's make sure we don't try to do `succ maxBound`:

```
isSuccessorOf x y = y /= maxBound && x == succ y
```

Let's try it again:

```
λ> isSuccessorOf 3 (maxBound :: Int)
False
λ> isSuccessorOf 3 (2 :: Integer)
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • No instance for (Bounded Integer)
        arising from a use of ‘isSuccessorOf’
    • In the expression: isSuccessorOf 3 (2 :: Integer)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = isSuccessorOf 3 (2 :: Integer)
```

Hmm, now it only works on bounded types. I'd like to avoid needing a separate function for unbounded and bounded `Enum`s, especially if there's nothing at compile-time to keep you from using the unbounded function on a bounded type. Let's use an `Ord` constraint instead:

```
isSuccessorOf x y = x > y && x == succ y
```

And let's try it:

```
λ> isSuccessorOf 3 (maxBound :: Int)
False
λ> isSuccessorOf 3 (2 :: Integer)
True
```

But now I'm making an unwarranted assumption. Let's try one more thing (note: this depends on `Down` having an `Enum` instance, which it only has in GHC 8.10):

```
λ> import Data.Ord (Down(..))
λ> let delisleFreezing = Down 150
λ> isSuccessorOf (succ delisleFreezing) delisleFreezing
False
```

Well that's less than ideal.

So is there any way to do this seemingly-simple task, without one of these three flaws?

- Fails to compile for types that aren't `Bounded`
- Bottoms for types that are `Bounded`
- Gives the wrong answer for types where `succ x > x` doesn't hold

Comment: You can perhaps use `fromEnum` to map it on `Int`s, but this is in fact also one of the "weak spots" of the `Enum` imho: that not all values per se fit in the `Int` range :(

Comment: Perhaps using `enumFrom` is better, since we can then just do pattern matching on the list.

Comment: What does GHCI say when you do like `succ $ Data.Ord.Down 150`?

Comment: @Redu `Down 151`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That looks interesting indeed: `succMaybe x = case [x..] of (_:z:_) -> Just z ; _ -> Nothing`. You should write an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a more safe way to check this is making use of [**`enumFromTo`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromTo), and check if the second item of the list is the successor we are looking for. We can, like [you say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688753/how-can-i-determine-if-one-enum-value-is-the-successor-of-another/61688937#comment109118183_61688937), simply pattern match on a list with two elements, we do not need to check if that second element is indeed `y`:

```
isSuccessorOf :: Enum a => a -> a -> Bool
isSuccessorOf y x
    | [_,_] <- [x .. y] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

or we can, like [@chi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688753/how-can-i-determine-if-one-enum-value-is-the-successor-of-another#comment109118049_61688753) use this to look if there is a successor:

```
succMaybe :: Enum a => a -> Maybe a
succMaybe x = case [x ..] of
    (_:z:_) -> Just z
    _ -> Nothing
```

Comment: Wait, we can lose the `Eq` constraint too! `isSuccessorOf y x = case [x..y] of [_,_] -> True; _ -> False`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Who can resist such a great golfing opportunity? `(0 <$ [x..y]) == [0,0]`... okay, so `length [x..y] == 2` is even shorter, but it has worse asymptotic performance. =P

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Nice, but note that in such case you'll have `isSuccessor 1.7 1.0`, since the float/double instance is a bit bogus.

Comment: @chi Yeah, that's a pretty awful instance in general. IMO, their `succ` and `pred` should do what [`nextafter`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nextafter.3.html) does, but I think it's a bit too late to change that now.

Comment: @chi It also doesn't bother me too much since using `==` on floating-point types is almost always the wrong thing to do anyway.