# Breaking a list on a given value into a list of sublists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, sublist

The `multipleLists` function needs to remove a given value from a list and return a list of lists. These sub lists group each element until it hits the value that needs to be removed. when this happens, a new sub list starts.

```
input:           multipleLists 'b' "abcabc"
expected output: ["a","ca","c"]
actual output:   ["a","c","a","c"]

input:           multipleLists 1 [0,1,2,3,4,1,3,4]
expected output: [[0],[2,3,4],[3,4]]
actual output:   [[0],[2],[3],[4],[3],[4]]
```

I think there is something wrong in the `otherwise` case but I'm a bit stuck.

Here is my code:

```hs
multipleLists :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
multipleLists value list = case list of 
    [] -> [] 
    [x] -> [[x]]
    x:xs 
        | value == x -> multipleLists value xs 
        | otherwise ->  [x] : (multipleLists value xs)
```

Comment: What would the value of `multipleLists 1 [1]` be?

Comment: an empty list - []

Comment: is your first example wrong? Shouldn't that be `["a","ca","c"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of yours using an accumulator - it does not use anything external besides `reverse` (which you could remove by changing the way the accumulator is build-up):

```hs
multipleLists :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
multipleLists value = go []
  where
  go [] [] = []
  go [] (x:xs)
    | x == value = go [] xs
    | otherwise = go [x] xs
  go acc [] = [reverse acc]
  go acc (x:xs)
    | x == value = reverse acc : go [] xs
    | otherwise = go (x:acc) xs
```

your examples (see my comment above):

```hs
> multipleLists 'b' "abcabc"
["a","ca","c"]

> multipleLists (1 :: Int) [0,1,2,3,4,1,3,4]
[[0],[2,3,4],[3,4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```hs
multipleListsAllowEmpty value list = 
    let (beginning, end) = break (value ==) list
    in beginning : case end of
        [] -> []
        (_:xs) -> multipleListsAllowEmpty value xs

multipleLists value = filter (not . null) . multipleListsAllowEmpty
```

Here, we import `break` from `Data.List`.

We can express `multipleListsAllowEmpty` even more compactly by

```hs
maybeTail [] = Nothing
maybeTail (_:xs) = Just xs

multipleListsAllowEmpty value = 
    toList . unfoldr (fmap maybeTail . break (value ==))
```

where we import `unfoldr` and `toList` from `Data.List.NonEmpty`.

Comment: is there a way to do it without importing anything?

Comment: your `unfoldr`-based code doesn't typecheck. it does if you replace `fmap` with `traverse`, but then it skips the last group in the output.

Answer (score 1):

What is the intended value of `multipleLists 0 [0, 0]`?

Is it `[]` or `[[]]` or `[[], []]`?

Here are two solutions that treat these cases differently, both based on a right fold.

```hs
splitList :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitList x = tail . foldr sx [[]] . (x:)
  where
    sx y ws@(zs:zss) | y == x    = [] : ws
                     | otherwise = (y:zs) : zss

multipleLists :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
multipleLists x = filter (not . null) . foldr sx [[]] . (x:)
  where 
    sx y ws@(zs:zss) | y == x    = [] : ws
                     | otherwise = (y:zs) : zss
```

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14403413/849891)